# Why do I see CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener(RDP-Tcp) when I'm not using RDP?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

What does this event mean?

```
Event 229, RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS

'CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener(RDP-Tcp) DEBUG/VM/ReverseTCP/ReverseUDP/INET' in CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener at 4087 err=[0x0]
```

I have RDP disabled, and as far as I can remember I've never used it on my computer.  So why am I seeing what appears to be an attempt to create an RDP listener?

I'm using Windows 10 21H2.

More related events following that one at same timestamp are:

```
Event ID 229:
'Creating standard listener:RDP-Tcp' in CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener at 4167 err=[0x0]

Event ID 229:
'Windows 8 or later detected, setting transport default mode to UDP + TCP' in CUMRDPListenerBase::Initialize at 470 err=[0x0]

Event ID 70:
The listener listens with display driver rdpudd.dll available.
```

It happens on different days, but not every day.

Answer (score 0):

You state, "I have RDP disabled,"  but you can also disable the underlying services to prevent some of these calls. See the [Black Viper list of extraneous Windows services](https://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/) for those safe to stop.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type *services.msc*, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Scroll down to *Remote Desktop...*.
- Double-click each of the three services and set *Startup type:* to *Disabled*.
- You can also disable the *Hyper-V Remote Desktop Virtualization Service*, for good measure.

[image: Remoe Desktop Services]

Comment: Ah, indeed I did have those running.  They're set to Manual start.  I'm not sure what needs them that is starting them, it's not clear from the dependencies.  I've disabled them, though.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. That Black Viper list is most useful.